# Visual Studio 2010 Crashes on Model Browser

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash

Guys anyone with the same problem?
Often crashes in model browser, the computer stops for a while (5seconds) without response and back again after a black screen (like when we up the previleges)

I went to the event viewer and i saw this message:

**The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

(devenv.exe, PID 2556, Thread 1) TuipPackage.InitializeTestProjectPlugins: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestPackage, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestPackage, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Tips.TuipPackage.TuipPackage.InitializeTestProjectPlugins()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
**

Comment: I'm getting this error, how'd you go fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message has been logged on MS Connect but it's mostly related to the Testing tools....

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/543848/vsttexecution-failure

Have you tried repairing your install?

Answer (score 0):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/578148/vsttexecution-errors-in-event-log-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-microsoft-visualstudio-qualitytools-codeduitestpackage

Workaround #2 worked for me:

I had similar problem, here is the workaround:

The issue might be your .suo file. If you don't find your .suo file besides the .sln file in the project then try this one.

Rename the folder which contains the solution & other files. Make sure that you have the .suo before opening the solution in VS 2010 IDE.

The issue is resolved. At least for me it worked.